# Eclemma is not working with Powermockito

Tags: junit

I want to coverage test case with Powermockito. But, it isn't working. If I comment @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class), Eclemma run. 
Please help me. Guide me coverage Powermockito.
Thanks.